# Nexus proxy will not fetch artifact

Tags: nexus

We have a Nexus OSS instance set up to host one repo and proxy several others, so the Maven settings.xml is then set up with our instance to be *. This works for most artifacts but one repo fails all of the time.

The failing repo is a snapshot one in another proprietory one within the company and I've set it up as a proxy repo (with snapshots allowed), added this proxy to the main Group and pointed Maven towards http://servername:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/. Maven now fails when it asks for the artifact (and also for the metadata) and indeed browsing to the location it mentions shows that it does not exist. Interestingly, the directory of the SNAPSHOT shows as existing, with only metadata and no artifact or POM, but even the link to maven-metadata.xml fails with a 404.

When I use the group's "Browse Index" tab in the GUI I see the artifact, with a repo path of http://servername:8081/nexus/service/local/repositories/public/content/<groupId/artifactId-with-version&gt; (Not Cached) and this fails too. The remote repository does contain it though!

Actually, going to the proxy in the GUI I can download the artifact from **servername:8081/nexus/service/local/repositories/<snapshot-repo>/content/<groupId/artifactId-with-version>**. So it feels like maybe a problem with the Group but I can't see any options that I can change to affect this, nor anything in the logs to indicate what's happening.

Although I've seen a couple of similar questions here already, I couldn't see any solution suggested. I'm happy to be proved wrong!

Comment: Check if the proxy repository is confiugred for the snapshot policy.

Comment: Repository policy is set to "Snapshot", if that's what you mean. If not, what else can I check?

Comment: Which nexus version are you using?

Answer (score 4):

See this article for troubleshooting tips:  https://support.sonatype.com/entries/21437881-Troubleshooting-Artifact-Download-Failures

In particular, the ?describe diagnostic URL mentioned at the bottom of the article will help you figure this out.

Comment: Looks like the article moved to https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213464518